# If $x$ is positive in $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2=x$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is positive, then show that there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2=x$.

Comment: Hint: Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: how should i do this?please help me..

Comment: Typically, you pick the least upper bound of some set.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^{2}$ is continuous, unbounded above and satisfies $f(0) = 0$, so following André Nicolas' comment, $f$ attains every positive real number. Maybe you want to prove this with simpler tools, though.

Comment: If you have not yet proved the IVT, you will have to go back to basics and use the hint of G. Sassatelli.

Comment: Does this analysis course teach the intermediate value thereon and continuous functions before this? Or does this course teach least upper bound principal first?

Comment: yeah i get it...it's really helpful...thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: I think using the IVT is circular.  To use IVT we need to know $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous and to know that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous we need to know that for all $x$ there is an $a^2 = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(y)=y^2-x$, Note that $f(0)<0$ and $f(x+1)>0$. So by Intermediate Value Theorem there exist a $y_o$ between $0$ and $x+1$ such that $f(y)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the intermediate value theorem applied to the function f(a) = a^2 - x, since
$f(0) \leq 0$ and $f(x + 1) \geq 0$.

By the IVT there exists a $a \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Another way: Let
$$x_{n+1} := \frac{1}{2} (x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}).$$
With $x_0 = a \geq 0$. Show that this sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}$ by showing that it is bounded from below ($x_n^2 \geq a, x_n \geq 0$) and decreasing. Show that the limit is a squareroot of $a$.